Intellij IDEA 2024.1 - Community Edition
enter image description here
Hi guy.
Does anyone have a problem with intellij IDE Community Edition? Every time it runs a building looks like this
I'm have a MacBook with macOS Sonoma. I did a new installation, but not working.

This is a known issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-43557
Workaround: switch to NewUI ("Settings | Appearance & Behavior | New UI | Enable NewUI")
